# Getting the code of released key

Tags: actionscript-2, keycode, keyrelease

I'm trying to make a simple platformer using action script 2.0 but I have a problem with getting input from keyboard. I have two function "myKeyDown" and "myKeyUp" that get called whenever a key is pressed down/released.

```
keyListener.onKeyDown = function(){
myKeyDown();
}
keyListener.onKeyUp = function(){
myKeyUp();
}
```

The functions check which key was pressed by using Key.getCode() method. It works for myKeyDown but it's buggy for myKeyUp. The bug happens if (for example) I first press A (to move left), then W (to jump), then release W and then release A. The player won't stop moving (even though that's what should happen when you release A)

I understand the problem here. Key.getcode return the code of the last pressed key and what I want is the code for the last released key. I've been searching for hours for a function like this but I haven't found anything.

Here's the code for both myKeyDown and myKeyUp functions

```
function myKeyDown(){
//A
if(Key.getCode() == 65){
    velX=-3;
}else
//D
if(Key.getCode() == 68){
    velX=3;
}else
//W
if(Key.getCode() == 87){
    if(isInAir == false){
        jump();
    }
}

}

function myKeyUp(){
//A
if(Key.getCode() == 65){
    if(velX==-3){
        velX=0;
    }
}else
//D
if(Key.getCode() == 68){
    if(velX==3){
        velX=0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Mixing event and polling, always problems. Even if you store the state of they keys you are at the mercy of when the eventhandler fires. If you google actionscript multiple keys, you'll get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

for cases like this, when you need to hold/release multiple keys a little bit different approach would be better for key handling.

what you can do is use onEnterFrame event listener to check for the pressed keys in case of events when something has to be continuous.

an example

```
var my_keys:Array = new Array();
my_keys["jump"]=false;
my_keys["right"]=false;
my_keys["left"]=false;

//keydown sets the variables to true
keyListener.onKeyDown = function(){
  code=Key.getCode();
  if(code==65){
    my_keys["left"]=true;
  }
  if(code==68){
    my_keys["right"]=true;
  }
  if(code==87){
    my_keys["jump"]=true;
  }
  //etc, etc, anything else you wish
  //of course, this doesn't prevent you from calling additional one-time events from the keydown!
}
//keyup unsets the button variables 
keyListener.onKeyUp = function(){
  code=Key.getCode();
  if(code==65){
    my_keys["left"]=false;
  }
  if(code==68){
    my_keys["right"]=false;
  }
  if(code==87){
    my_keys["jump"]=false;
  }
}
```

now at every point of your game you have a set of keys that are pressed stored in the my_keys array. of course you could use a more generic function inside the keyDown/keyUp and pass the Key.getCode itself directly into the array as indexes instead of the captioned array (like `my_keys[Key.getCode()]=true;`), it would be even shorter to write. however, i found this to be more illustrative as an example, feel free to modify the code as you need

what you want now is a function that would handle the behavior based on what keys are pressed.

in your case this could, for example, be:

```
this.onEnterFrame=function(){ //you don't have to use "this" movieclip reference if you have other enterframe events in the movieclip. just don't forget to modify the objcet paths
  if(my_keys["left"]){
    velX=-3;
  }
  if(my_keys["right"]){
    velX=+3;
  }
  if((my_keys["jump"])&&(!isInAir)){ //note that i added !isInAir instead of (isInAir==false). this is an equivalent expression, it's just shorter and nicer
    jump();
  }
}
```